# OpenCV Mat::zeros not filled with 0

Tags: c++, opencv, unsigned-integer, opencv-mat

I have this code:

```
Mat Marker = Mat::zeros(MarkerSize, MarkerSize, CV_8UC1);

cout << "Marker:" << endl;
for (int row=0; row<MarkerSize; row++)
{
for (int col=0; col<MarkerSize; col++)
cout << Marker.at<int>(row, col)<<", ";

cout << endl;
}
```

where `MarkerSize=6` and `CV_8UC1` is preferably not changeable (for solution).

But I get this output:

```
Marker:
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 65536, -1664876544, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1141152964, 289879, 
0, 65536, -1664876544, 1817658372, 1531445252, 2147447774,
```

How come and how can I fix it?

Comment: `Marker.at<int>(row, col)` // <-- Marker.at<uchar>

Comment: in other words, your Mat got initialized all ok, you're just accessing it wrong , while checking the result. (btw, try to avoid writing per-pixel loops, rather do `cout << Marker << endl;` )

Comment: `Marker.at<int>(row, col)` does not work the output is `Marker:
, , , , , , 
, , , , , , 
, , , , , , 
, , , , , , 
, , , , , , 
, , , , , , `. This though `cout << Marker << endl;` works and the output is a zeros matrix. Now the question is the what is the type `Marker.at<???>(row, col)` ?

Comment: again, the opencv folks already have a solution here, which is: print out the whole Mat at a time. (cout << Marker << endl;)

Comment: again, with opencv, - if you're trying to write your own per-pixel things, - chances are high, that you've missed some higher order function, that does the very same thing without errors and faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Mat` object is instantiated with `CV_8UC1`, that is, containing `MarkerSize*MarkerSize` 8 bit unsigned elements. But you iterate over it as if it container `int`s, going out of bounds in the iteration. For example, by accessing the elements with

```
Marker.at<uint8_t>(row, col)
```

Note that to print this you may have to cast to a different integer type, because `uint8_t` could be interpreted by `std::cout` as a `char`. For example

```
cout << static_cast<int>(Marker.at<uint8_t>(row, col)) <<", ";
```

Comment: Output for `Marker.at<uint8_t>(row, col) `: `Marker:
, , , , , , 
, , , , , , 
, , , , , , 
, , , , , , 
, , , , , , 
, , , , , , `.

And for `dynamic_cast<int>(Marker_thresh.at<uint8_t>(row, col))` the error message is `'int' is not a reference or pointer`...

Comment: `cout << static_cast<int>(Marker.at<uint8_t>(row, col)) <<", ";` works also, thank you! And what type do I have to use, when I want to change a certain value in `Marker`? `Marker.at<uchar>(row,col)=255;`? Is `uchar` the correct type?